# .hgignore Filtering out all similar folder structures

Tags: c#, regex, mercurial, hgignore

I've got many C# class libraries in one repository. I want to blanket ignore all files that exist in a /obj/Debug/ folder, no matter where they may exist. They may exist at basically any depth within the individual projects.

Examples:

RepositoryMainFolder\MainProject\obj\Debug\
RepositoryMainFolder\RepositoryMainFolder.Internal.ProjectA\SbiLib.Internal.ProjectA\obj\Debug\
RepositoryMainFolder\RepositoryMainFolder.Internal.ProjectB\RepositoryMainFolder.Internal.ProjectB\obj\Debug\

So far I've tried a few methods, but this seems like what I'm after, but it doesn't seem to work.

.hgignore:

```
syntax: glob
RepositoryMainFolder/*/obj/Debug/*
RepositoryMainFolder/*/obj/x64/Debug/*
```

I've already tried doing the same thing under the regex syntax and it doesn't work either.

Comment: Does `**/obj/**` ignore everything under all `obj` folders at any depth? I haven't had a chance to thouroughly test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, glob syntax is "shell-style"; on both Windows and Unixen, for example, `*` does not recurse into subdirectories, but matches a single file/folder. Apparently Mercurial [supports the `**` glob](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/file-names-and-pattern-matching.html), which *does* recurse:

```
syntax: glob
RepositoryMainFolder/**/obj/Debug/
RepositoryMainFolder/**/obj/x64/Debug/
```

With Mercurial, the globs are not absolute paths, though -- so you can simply write:

```
syntax: glob
/obj/Debug/
/obj/x64/Debug/
```

Or even just

```
syntax: glob
/obj/
```

With a regular expression, `*` is not a wildcard per se, but a *quantifier* that means zero-or-more of whatever came before. `.` matches any character in a regex, so you could write:

```
syntax: regexp
RepositoryMainFolder/.*/obj/Debug/
RepositoryMainFolder/.*/obj/x64/Debug/
```

Comment: This is an incredible answer. So far I've been using nearly all of these little tricks with great success. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Zachary: Yeah, no problem :-)